# How to get rid of the blank areas around alphabetical images?

Tags: graphics

I attempt to test the mean graylevels of the alphabets "W" and "Z". I used the following code to create the images of them.

```
imW = Rasterize@
  Graphics[ 
   Text[Style["W", 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
     TextAlignment -> Center, Antialiasing -> True], {0, 0}], 
   ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 24]

imZ = Rasterize@
  Graphics[ 
   Text[Style["Z", 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
     TextAlignment -> Center, Antialiasing -> True], {0, 0}], 
   ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 24]
```

However, there are blank areas around the images. How can I get rid of them? Is there a trim function built in for this purpose?

[image]

I tried `ImageCrop[imW ]`, however, the top and bottom blanks still left.

@kirma I did follow your suggestions, both increasing the `ImagePadding` to 20, and `ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img]]`. Somehow, I still can't get rid of the top and bottom blanks. What I got was something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these appear to work on my system (v10, Windows):

```
img1 = ImageCrop@
   Graphics[Text @ Style["W", 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Antialiasing -> True]];

img2 = ImageCrop@
   Rasterize@Style["W", 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Antialiasing -> True];
```

Comment: Your codes are always clean and straight to the point! I would like to ask one more thing, what would be your code for the image when the "W" and "Z" overlapped each other?

Comment: @user16069 Does this work as you desire? `ImageCrop @ Graphics[Text[Style[#, 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Antialiasing -> True], {#2, 0}] & ~MapThread~ {{"W", "Z"}, {0, 0.07}}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got exactly what I want now:
`ImageCrop@Graphics[ Text[ Style[#, 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Antialiasing -> True]] & ~MapThread~ {{"W", "Z"} }]` instead of my adoption of your previous answer:  `ImageCrop@Graphics[{Text@Style["W", 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Antialiasing -> True], Text@Style["Z", 24, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Antialiasing -> True]}] `  With your code I can obtain the overlapped images from a list of alphabets more easily now.

Answer (score 6):

Use `ImageCrop`. It does exactly what you want, at least in this case... except in the case where "empty" space exists only on one side of the image, which it refuses to crop. To work around that, you can use `ImagePadding` or `ImagePad` to create extra padding, which allows `ImageCrop` to see removable padding on all sides.

**EDIT**:

Other, a bit less hacky alternative is `ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img]]`.

```
ImagePad[imW, -BorderDimensions[imW]]
```

[image]

```
ImagePad[imZ, -BorderDimensions[imZ]]
```

[image]